# Declaration of DoctrineORMEntityManager ::initializeProxy() must be compatible with ProxyManager\Proxy\LazyLoadingInterface::initializeProxy(): bool

Tags: php, symfony, php-7.2, symfony-2.8

When I type this command 
`php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug` or this one `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

I got the following error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of DoctrineORMEntityManager_0000000035a1d9b70000558a7db0d6e7da5c7b8013722216782206eefb5b6fe5::initializeProxy() must be compatible with ProxyManager\Proxy\LazyLoadingInterface::initializeProxy(): bool in /var/www/myproject/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 4459
```

FYI

```
php --version
PHP 7.2.28 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2020 11:07:04) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

It used to worked when I used php 5.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/Ocramius/ProxyManager/issues/378) will be of some help?

Comment: Actually it did ! 
but before I had to empty my "cache" directory by hand.
So I did : 
`rm -rf app/cache/prod/
php72 composer.phar dump-autoload
php72 composer.phar install --optimize-autoloader`

And I get some warning but so far it seems to work... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So has I said in comment I don't have this error anymore :
 I had to empty my "cache" directory by hand. So I did : `rm -rf app/cache/prod/` 
`php72 composer.phar dump-autoload`
`php72 composer.phar install --optimize-autoloader`

And I get some warnings but so far it seems to work... :) –